# Управление SVG подключенного через img

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация

Можно ли, с помощью JS, как-то управлять стилями, атрибутами `svg`, который подключен через тег `img` ?

Comment: на 99% - ответ нет, этот 1 процент я изображу попозже, но, я думаю вы догадываетесь о чем я :)

Comment: если честно, то не очень)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Считайте что нет, разве что вот так:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {

  let svg = `<svg height="100" width="100"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" 
    r="${Math.sin(t/1000)*20+25}"
    fill="hsl(${t/10},55%,55%)"/>
</svg>`
 
  img.setAttribute("src", 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg))
  
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);

}
```

```html
<img id=img>
```

Comment: благодарю, за подсказку)

Answer (score 3):

Вдохновленный ответом @StrangerintheQ, придумал вот такую реализацию. Из-за кросс-доменности запросов, здесь не получается воспроизвести результат. Но локально все работает.

```js
const img_origin = document.getElementById('img_origin');
const src  = img_origin.src;

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', src, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 xhr.send();
console.log('Запрос ушел');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
const result = xhr.responseText;
console.log(result)
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(result, "application/xml");
const svg = doc.querySelector('svg');
svg.setAttribute('stroke', 'red')
svg.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
const str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg)
const img_modify = document.getElementById('img_modify');
img_modify.setAttribute("src", 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(str))
  }
};
```

```html
 <img id="img_origin" src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlelogo/svg/googlelogo_dark_clr_112x36px.svg" alt="">
    <img id="img_modify"  alt="">
```

Comment: Да, примерно так и можно поступать =) и можно обойтись без domparser и xmlserializer